# Ansible golang timeout

Tags: ansible

I'm getting a timeout when installing with go within an Ansible playbook with packer. It only happens when building a 32bit image, it does not occur when building a 64bit image.

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "export GOPATH=$HOME/go && export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH/bin && go mod tidy && make && make install", "delta": "0:10:07.743351", "end": "2023-11-06 01:18:11.028730", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-11-06 01:08:03.285379", "stderr":
net/http: TLS handshake timeout"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The ansible playbook works perfectly with cloning from GitHub. So there are no connection issues, but somehow the make command does timeout after 10 minutes. And only on building a 32-bit image, no issues when builing a 64-bit image.

```yaml
    - name: install pwngrid 1.10.4
      shell: "export GOPATH=$HOME/go && export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH/bin && go mod tidy && make && make install"
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        chdir: /usr/local/src/pwngrid
```

I tried the `timeout: 3600` attribute. But that only makes the task wait 1 hour I think. If this question is off-topic for stackoverflow, I'm sorry.

Comment: There might be a correlation between the error message `net/http: TLS handshake timeout` and "_only on building a 32-bit image_" which might be a good starting point for further research.